# Non-Binary Significance Testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

It's been awhile since I've done significance testing... I need to compare 2 average scores:

Score A is 7.9 on a 0-10 scale (11pt scale). Score B is 8.2 on a 0-10 scale (11pt scale). The samples sizes are A=70 and B=300. How do I determine if the change in average score is significant or not?

Comment: There's no enough information to give an answer; at the very least you also need the standard deviations (though I guess one can at least derive a bound on them). Given the sample sizes, I'd be inclined to consider a two-sample t-test.

Comment: A randomization (/permutation) test would be another possibility.

Answer (score 2):

***THIS*** sounds like a job for the [rank sum test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U)! The test is widely available in statistical software packages, and is a nonparametric analog to the [unpaired *t* test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Independent_.28unpaired.29_samples).

Your null hypothesis in this case is H$_{0}\text{: P}(A > B) = 0.5$—that is, the probability that a randomly selected observation from group *A* is greater than a randomly selected observation from group *B* is one half.

Your alternative hypothesis is H$_{\text{A}}\text{: P}(A > B) \ne 0.5$—that is, one of the groups (either *A* or *B*) *stochastically dominates* the other group.

**If** the distributions of scores in groups *A* and *B* are the same shape, and are only shifted up or down relative to one another, then you can interpret this test as a test for median difference with the corresponding H$_{0}\text{: }\tilde{x}_{\text{A}} = \tilde{x}_{\text{B}}$ and H$_{\text{A}}\text{: }\tilde{x}_{\text{A}} \ne \tilde{x}_{\text{B}}$.

Alternatively, (if this is the end of your analysis, and you won't, for example, down the road become interested in a third group, *C*) you could simply use the aforementioned unpaired *t* test for *mean difference*, where H$_{0}\text{: }\bar{x}_{\text{A}} = \bar{x}_{\text{B}}$ and H$_{\text{A}}\text{: }\bar{x}_{\text{A}} \ne \bar{x}_{\text{B}}$.